# How to filter by field name in model manager (NameError)

Tags: django, django-model-field

**models.py**

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    student = models.OneToOneField(
    User, related_name='student', primary_key=True, parent_link=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    membership_end = models.DateTimeField(
    verbose_name="Membership End Date", default=now, editable=False)

    objects = StudentProfileManager()
```

**managers.py**

```
class StudentQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def get_student_chat_list(self):
        return self.filter(membership_end >= datetime.Now()).values_list('student_id', 'chat_user_sid')

class StudentProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return StudentQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)

    def get_student_chat_list(self):
        return self.get_queryset().get_student_chat_list()
```

This should have a very simple explanation, but I don't understand what's wrong here.  I'm getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'membership_end' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
return self.filter(membership_end__gte=datetime.Now()).values_list('student_id', 'chat_user_sid')
```

I don't think you can use `>=` or `<=`, so You have to use `gte` or `lte`. Everything in your code looks fine. So, I doubt `>=` is causing that error. [Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#gte)